# How to prevent Scrollview expand beyond its maximum usable space for expanding

Tags: xamarin.forms, layout, constraints, overlap

[image: What is the problem to resolve!]

I think i have tried everything possible but i'm also sure that i have the nose too close from the window to see clearly after 5 days trying constraining the expansion of the scrollviewer. I would like it to remain under the stact layout of the thumbnail viewer.  Represented by the red line.  Any  help or solution would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Frame
    x:Class="EchoMessager.Pages.ListeMessages.MessageEditor"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:resx="clr-namespace:EchoMessager.Resx"
    xmlns:k="clr-namespace:EchoMessager;assembly=EchoMessager"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EchoMessager"
    xmlns:ctrls="clr-namespace:EchoMessager.Controls;assembly=EchoMessager"
    xmlns:ctrl="clr-namespace:EchoMessager.Controls.MessageEditor;assembly=EchoMessager"
    x:Name="EditorControlsPresenterContainer"
    VerticalOptions="End">
    <FlexLayout
        Direction="Column"
        JustifyContent="End">
        <!--  Thumbnail Presenter  -->
        <StackLayout
            x:Name="ThumbnailPlaceHolder"
            Margin="0"
            Padding="0"
            Orientation="Vertical"
            VerticalOptions="End"
            Spacing="0"
            BackgroundColor="#545454">
            <ctrls:CloseOpenSwitch
                x:Name="PreviewPresenterControlSwith"
                IsVisible="True"
                VerticalOptions="End"
                State="disabled" />

            <!--  Row #2 - Thumbnails Viewer Implementation  -->
            <CollectionView
                x:Name="ThumbnailsPresenter"
                Margin="0"
                VerticalOptions="End"
                SelectionMode="Single"
                IsVisible="true"
                HeightRequest="95"
                MinimumHeightRequest="95"
                ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureAllItems"
                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
                <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                    <LinearItemsLayout
                        Orientation="Horizontal"
                        SnapPointsType="MandatorySingle"
                        SnapPointsAlignment="Center"
                        ItemSpacing="8" />
                </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="{x:Type ctrl:ThumbnailModel}">
                        <Image
                            Margin="1"
                            Aspect="AspectFit"
                            Source="{Binding Thumbnail, Mode=OneWay}">
                            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding OpenCommand, Mode=OneWay}" />
                            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        </Image>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
        </StackLayout>

        <!--  Editor Row  -->
        <StackLayout
            x:Name="EditorControlsPresenter"
            Margin="0"
            Padding="0"
            BackgroundColor="GreenYellow"
            Orientation="Horizontal"
            VerticalOptions="End">

            <Image
                x:Name="cameraButton"
                Margin="0"
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                FlexLayout.AlignSelf="Start"
                WidthRequest="60"
                HeightRequest="60"
                BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                Source="camerabutton.png">
                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnPrendrePhoto" />
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>

            <ScrollView
                x:Name="MessagesViewScrollingArea"
                Margin="0"
                Padding="0"
                HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                VerticalOptions="End"
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
                <!--  What is about to be scroll  -->
                <Editor
                    x:Name="EntrerMessage"
                    Margin="0"
                    VerticalOptions="End"
                    FlexLayout.Grow="1"
                    AutoSize="TextChanges"
                    Keyboard="Default"
                    MaxLength="1500"
                    Placeholder="{x:Static resx:AppResources.MessageEntryPlaceholder}"
                    Text="{Binding Message.Texte, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    Unfocused="EntrerMessage_OnUnfocused"
                    FontSize="{OnPlatform Default=Default,
                                          Converter={StaticResource FontNamedSizeToDouble}}">
                </Editor>
            </ScrollView>

            <AbsoluteLayout
                HorizontalOptions="End"
                VerticalOptions="Center">
                <Image
                    x:Name="envoyerMessageButton"
                    Margin="0"
                    HeightRequest="60"
                    WidthRequest="60"
                    Source="sendbutton.png">
                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnSendMessage" />
                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                </Image>
                <ActivityIndicator
                    x:Name="activityIndicator"
                    Margin="0"
                    HeightRequest="60"
                    WidthRequest="60"
                    IsRunning="false"
                    IsVisible="false"
                    Opacity="0.8"
                    Color="Black" />
            </AbsoluteLayout>
        </StackLayout>
        <!--  Editor tools  -->
        <!--  Bouton Coller  -->
        <Button
            x:Name="boutonCollerMessage"
            Margin="0"
            Padding="10,0"
            IsVisible="false"
            FontSize="Micro"
            BackgroundColor="Blue"
            FlexLayout.AlignSelf="Stretch"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            Text="Coller le message"
            Clicked="OnCollerMessage" />
    </FlexLayout>
</Frame>
```

Comment: Hi , sorry for not too much understanding the screenshot and code, could you expain that with another image by drawing manually?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there is a seriously strange bug with xamarin.forms and we found around here that fwe must put this proporty to true on a stacklayout containing many children to make allow it to behave as expected. simply add stacklayoutname.IsTabStop=False;